# Unable to install MySQL Workbench

Tags: apt, mysql, pop-os

When i try to install the official MySQL Workbench, it shows dependency issue of the unavailabilty of libproj19. However the repos only has libproj22 when i tried to install from APT.

Can someone help me out?

```
System:   Host: cosmic Kernel: 5.16.19-76051619-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Console: pty pts/1 Distro: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
```

```
karthik@cosmic:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.28-1ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community.
(Reading database ... 629535 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community_8.0.28-1ubuntu21.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (8.0.28-1ubuntu21.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
mysql-workbench-community depends on libproj19 (>= 7.2.0); however:
Package libproj19 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-workbench-community
karthik@cosmic:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install libproj19
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libproj19 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libproj19' has no installation candidate
```

```
karthik@cosmic:~/Downloads$ apt list -i | grep "libproj"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libproj22/jammy,now 8.2.1-1 amd64 [installed]
karthik@cosmic:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Pretty dumb way but it works.

I narrowed down each conflicting dependecies and manually installed the required versions as deb files from Debian/ubuntu repos.

Whenever one of them again had dependency conflicts, I repeated the same method for them.

It took me like around 30 mins doing this but finally got the .deb version of workbench working on 22.04

Answer (score 3):

The same under ubuntu 22.04 lts.
Try to use the snap!

```
snap install mysql-workbench-community
```

Only the settings from you previous apt install of mysql workbench are gone. Don't know, if there is a way to import the settings from ~/.mysql/workbench into your new snap install.

Answer (score -1):

This is way easier than I thought it would be. On Ubuntu, I just allowed all permissions on the app installer, and voila!